# Help.. needed... System Got into trouble after installing amdgpupro

Tags: 16.04, amdgpu

I recently Installed amdgpupro on Ubuntu 16.04 lts. After reboot my system is showning above message. I followed the process mentioned on official amd site.. after installalling amd packages next instruction is to reboot pc. And after reboot my system is showning following error.

The System is running in Low - graphics mode

Your screen, graphics card and input device could not be detected correctly. You will be configure these yourself.

On clicking ok.. it is showing 4 options 
1. Try running with default graphical mode
2 . Reconfigure graphics
3. Troubleshoot the error
4. Exit to console login.

I don't know how to Fix the current issue. Help needed Urgently.

I am using Lenovo z51-70 having hibrid graphics card... 
Previous my system is running on Intel 5500 graphics.. after Installing amggpu pro my system is showing this eroor.

Comment: are you using secure boot? Ubuntu kernels 4.3 and newer required signed modules if secure boot is enabled.

Comment: Secure boot has been disabled on my system

Comment: Rebooted my system after enabling secure boot. This time my system is showing logon screen then pc is going into trouble and again back to login screen.

Comment: Even unable to report issue can't even Connected to internet

Comment: that is because the kernel won't load the unsigned module. secure boot has to be off.

Comment: If secure boot has  disabled. it is showing low graphics mode mentioned in question...